# Class not found in call back function Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hitting an error in Laravel ServiceProvider,
class not found even though it exists, and it throws an error inside the call back function, (not before)
and btw it works fine locally but I got this error when deploying to GCP, might be a difference in php version or something? however what could a solution be here ?
my code:

```
<?php


namespace App\Services\Tableau;


use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Services\Tableau\TableauClient;

class TableauServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            TableauClient::class,
            function () {
                return new TableauClient(
                    config('services.tableau.server_url'),

                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

it throws error on this line

```
return new TableauClient(
                    config('services.tableau.server_url'),

                );
```

```
"Class 'App\Services\Tableau\TableauClient' not found"
```

what am I missing here ?

Comment: First double check namespace in `TableauClient` class. After that you can try `composer du`.

Comment: I did, it is the same, and it works fine locally! the error appears when deployed to app engine! and it seems the problem is inside the function(){ return new TableauClient} only

Comment: Also, is provider's namespace correct - shouldn't that be `namespace App\Providers\TableauServiceProvider;`?

Comment: just run `composer dump-autoload` on the server

Comment: what is the exact name of the class, its namespace, the filename and the path?

Answer (score 0):

Register the  Service Provider by adding the `TableauServiceProvider` class to `config/app.php`. Preferably, under Application Service Providers;

```php
/*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        // Add your service provider here...
```

Also, check the namespace for Provider class. By convention, all providers live in the `App\Providers` namespace.

However, if you want to stick to the setup you have which I wouldn't recommend, then you can register your `TableauServiceProvider` like below:

```php
App\Services\Tableau\TableauServiceProvider::class
```

as described above.

Hope this helps you out.